# In which Library of Jython, makeEmptyPicture function is available?

Tags: python, image, jython, jes

I just want to ask that in which library, makePictureEmpty(width, height) function is available?

Comment: JES has a function called `makeEmptyPicture` (not `makePictureEmpty`).  Are you asking if the function can be used outside of the JES environment?

Answer (score 0):

This might help- JES function called makeEmptyPicture() to create an "empty" canvas with a default color of white and width and height equal to the original image:
 http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/325/PythonPictures/

Comment: I know this. What I want is that how to use it? in which library it is? means that what I have to import to use this function?